# unable to print oracle database query data in php

Tags: php, oracle

I want to print a value that taken from oracle database. but it is showing error.
Below is my code.

```
<?php

// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
 $conn = oci_connect('FUNREAD', 'clock24', '10.6.8.51:1525/DRFUNPD1');
 if (!$conn) 
 {
 $e = oci_error();
 trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
 }

 $atp1 = oci_parse($conn, 'select count(*) as count from  ATP1.PENDING_MESSAGE');

 oci_execute($atp1);
 $atp1 = oci_fetch_array($atp1);
 echo $atp11;
 ?>
```

But I am not getting right output. Below output I am getting.

```
Resource id #4
```

Comment: Well you can't echo an array if that's what you're asking?

Comment: so please suggest what can i do... if i comment on that line..

Comment: Hint -- where did $apt11 come from ?

Comment: sorry type mistake...it will be $atp1

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo a resource result, where what you need to do is to either retrieve the first row and output that, or loop over the results and output them:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($atp1)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Note that fundamentally it's probably a good idea not to re-use the `$atp1` variable for both the query and the result set, use something more descriptive, e.g.:

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, 'select count(*) as count from ATP1.PENDING_MESSAGE');
oci_execute($query);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

I'm pretty much copying this straight out of [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php) (since I haven't used Oracle functions in PHP before)...